# Объявление переменных в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пользователь даёт ответы в виде строки, но для корректной её работы их нужно преобразовать в `boolean`.

Попытался сделать это через `if-else` в самом начале кода, но не вышло. Далее, весь уловный блок я вставил в функцию, но тут всплыла проблема с определением переменных внутри неё.

```py
def str_to_bool(answer):
    if ans1_w == 'Да':
        ans1 = True
    else:
        ans1 = False

    if ans2_w == 'Да':
        ans2 = True
    else:
        ans2 = False

    if ans3_w == 'Да':
        ans3 = True
    else:
        ans3 = False

    if ans4_w == 'Да':
        ans4 = True
    else:
        ans4 = False

    if ans5_w == 'Да':
        ans5 = True
    else:
        ans5 = False

    if ans6_w == 'Да':
        ans6 = True
    else:
        ans6 = False


ans1_w = input('\nЭто ты это сломал? ')
str_to_bool(ans1_w)
if ans1 == True:
    ans2_w = input('\nСвалить можешь? ')
else:
    ans2_w = input('\nНужно оно тебе? ')
if (ans1 and ans2) or (not ans1 and not ans2) == True:
    print('\nЗабей.')
if (ans1 == False and ans2 == True) or (ans1 == True and ans2 == False):
    ans3_w = input('\nНадо починить. Оно двигается, болтается, шатается, люфтит? ')
if ans3 == True:
    ans4_w = input('\nА должно ли оно люфтить? ')
    if ans4 == True:
        print('\nОна не сломана. А твой мозг - да. Тут не помогут даже фиксики.')
    else:
        ans5_w = input('\nПроблемы с финансовым положением имеются? ')
    if ans5 == True:
        ans6_w = input('\nВы верующий, религиозный, суеверный? ')
    if ans6 == True:
        print('\nСиняя изолента вам в помощь.')
    else:
        print('\nЧёрная изолента вам в помощь')
else:
    ans4_w = input('\nА должно ли оно люфтить? ')
```

Переменные `ans1-6` подчёркиваются красной волнистой линией как в функции, так и вне её. Я знаю, что есть оператор `bool()`, но там возвращается значение `False` только при вводе пустой строки, а это, в моём случае, неприемлемо.

Comment: Функция создаёт внутри себя локальные переменные, которые сразу же уничтожаются при завершении работы функции, потому что функция эти переменные никуда наружу себя не помещает. Так что в текущем виде функция полностью бесполезна и ничего не делает

Answer (score 5):

Напишите более универсальную функцию:

```
def get_answer(question):
    ans = input(question)
    return ans.strip().lower() in ("да", "конечно", "yes", "sure")
```

и пользуйтесь это функцией:

```
if get_answer('\nЭто ты это сломал? '):
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Можно создать функцию определения ответа (true/false) и ее дергать

```
def str_to_bool(answer):
   if answer == 'Да'
       return true
   else:
       return false

ans1_w = input('\nЭто ты это сломал? ')
ans1 = str_to_bool(ans1_w)
if ans1 == True:
    ans2_w = input('\nСвалить можешь? ')
else:
    .....
```

Comment: Вы хотя бы раз пробовали бы запускать свой код, прежде чем ответ писать

Comment: @andreymal я не сказал что это рабочий код и бла бла бла. Я дал пищу для размышлений.

Comment: В таком случае это не является ответом на вопрос и подлежит удалению.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/388331)

Comment: @xaja, неправильный ответ (например, с нерабочим кодом) также является ответом. Если у вас есть основания считать, что ответ неправильный - поставьте минус, но не используйте удаление через инструмент проверки, он предназначен не для этого.

Comment: @andreymal, в чем смысл ваших изменений ответа?

Comment: @MaxU в том, что вы и insolor противоречите намерениям автора ответа. Прочитайте второй комментарий к этому ответу.